# How can I detect if an email didn't reach a recipient? (Gmail SMTP, delivery failures)

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, gmail, swiftmailer

I've built a Laravel web app that uses Gmail's SMTP to send email to customers. Under the hood, I believe the driver uses SwiftMailer. Settings are working and emails sent are reaching customers.

However, as you can see in the following screenshot, if the customer had a typo when providing their email, my app will queue the email thinking everything's OK and won't know that the email didn't actually reach (in this case, cause recipient doesn't exist).

How do I deal with delivery failures (not just "email doesn't exist)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Swiftmailer forwards emails to an SMTP server. In your case the SMTP server is Gmail.

Gmail accepts your mail message, stores the email, and at a later time **attempts** to deliver the email to the recipient's mail servers.

The Swiftmailer only reports issues with transferring the email to the SMTP server. Once the transfer is complete, the Swiftmailer has no future knowledge of what is the final outcome of the email.

If you send an email to an incorrect recipient email address (the domain portion is correct):

- The recipient's email server rejects the email with an error.
- The recipient's email server accepts the email and later replies with a bounce message.
- The recipient's email server accepts the email and throws it away. The reason is to prevent abusers from detecting valid email accounts on the server.

If the domain part is incorrect and does not exist then Gmail will not be able to connect to the recipient's email server. Gmail typically continues to try to send the mail message at later date.

Note: There are many reasons for an email message not being delivered even if the recipient's email address is correct. Some reasons are SPAM, lack of disk space, resource exhaustion, SPF/DMARC/DKIM, etc.

> How do I deal with delivery failures (not just "email doesn't exist)?

If you are managing your own email via Gmail, you must manage email bounce and delivery failures manually. Gmail offers no features in this area.

If you are managing a mailing list, select a provider that manages the entire process for you.